# How to make a for loop go through two lists and print into one line

Tags: unity-game-engine

Any advice on how to run through two lists and adding respective entries into one line?

the following code says 'stri' is not recognized

```
sw.WriteLine("List of 2D screen space drag points where user dragged object");
    for each(str in startObjDragPosList && stri in deleteObjectList)
    {

        sw.WriteLine("[" + str+ "] was dragged:[" + stri + "] ");
        //separator for later analysis is $
        iDragPoint++;
    }
```

I am aware that I probably need to count through both lists, but that should be straight forward.
best,

Comment: Why not use a simple for loop with an index?

Comment: like 

        for(str in List)
{
   for(stri in List2.[index])
   {
       //do whatever
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this

```
if(trackPole1NameList.Count == trackPole2NameList.Count)
    {
        for(var o = 0;o<trackPole1NameList.Count;o++)
        {

            //sw.WriteLine("Pole1[" + o + trackPole1NameList[o] + "] Pole2: [" + trackPole2NameList[o] + "]");
            sw.WriteLine("Pole1[" + trackPole1NameList[o] + "] Pole2: [" + trackPole2NameList[o] + "]");
            //sw.WriteLine(o);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, exactly. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudocode, not tested:

```
foreach(str in list1) {
    foreach(stri in list2) {
        sw.WriteLine(str + ": " + stri);
    }
}
```

if you had two lists:

```
list1 = { "1", "2" };
list2 = { "A", "B" };
```

That loop should give you the output:

```
1: A
1: B
2: A
2: B
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: hey, thnx for answering.
the loop first runs through the first entry, then continues: Like below:
pole[0]: pole[0]target
pole[0]: pole[1]target
pole[0]: pole[2]target
pole[0]: pole[3]target
pole[1]: pole[0]target

I would really like it to print:
pole[0]: pole[0]target
pole[1]: pole[1]target
pole[2]: pole[2]target
thnx

Comment: @krodil Then just use a simple for loop with an integer index, assuming both lists are of the same length.

Comment: can you provide an example, alternatively comment on my faux pas solution? I already try to use a counter.

Comment: @Bart `code`
for(str in trackPole1NameList)
        {
         for(stri in trackPole2NameList)
         {
          sw.WriteLine(str + ": " + stri);
         }
        }
`code`
This prints out pole[0]: pole[0]target
pole[0]: pole[1]target
pole[1]: pole[0]target
pole[1]: pole[1]target
I want it to print index 0 & 0, 1 & 1, etc.